# trying to click a button on playwright

Tags: playwright

```
<input id="k" type="submit" class="btn btn_search" value="Search">
```

tried

```
await page.click('button:has-text("SEARCH")');
await page.click('button:has-text("Search")');
await page.click('button.btn.btn_search');
await page.click('button:btn.btn_search'); <-- not valid selector
await page.click('button#k');
await page.click('BUTTON[type="submit"]');
```

all end up with timeout (except where noted)

e.g. page.click: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "button#k"

Answer (score 8):

If you want to select a button with text the syntax is: `await page.locator('button:text("Button Text Here")');`.

So to click you would type: `await page.locator('button:text("Button Text Here")').click();`

Answer (score 1):

`has-text` is for text content between tags like `<div>my-text</div>`, but the input element holds it's text in the `value` property.

Also using `button` in the selector is only for `<button>` elements.

```js
await page.click('input#k')
await page.click('input[value="SEARCH"]')
await page.click('input.btn.btn_search')
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `getByRole` api which allows locating elements by their role, attributes and accessible name.
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-framelocator#frame-locator-get-by-role

You can locate each element by it's implicit role and in your case `button`:

```
await page.getByRole('button', { name: /search/i }).click();
```

An example for checkbox:

```
await page.getByRole('checkbox', { name: 'Subscribe' }).check();
```